# Rails logged_in? method not changing the navigation bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, stay-logged-in

I have a navigation bar that is displaying a different set of links based off if the user is signed in or not. I have setup a logged_in? method within a conditional statement in order to accomplish this. The problem is after I click the log in button and successfully sign in. The system doesn't alter the navigation bar as expected. I have to refresh the page or click another link in order to get it to register.

application.html.erb

```
<% if logged_in? %>
    <li><%= link_to "Oppurtunity", companies_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Pipeline", deals_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Tasks", tasks_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "My Account", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>          
    <li><%= link_to "Log Out", logout_path, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-default navbar-btn' %></li>
<% else %>
    <li><%= link_to "Log In", login_path, class: 'btn btn-default navbar-btn' %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Contact", new_contact_path %></li>
<% end %>
```

session_helper.rb

```
 # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
def current_user
  if (user_id = session[:user_id])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
  elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
    user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
    if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
      log_in user
      @current_user = user
    end
  end
end

def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
end
```

session_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
     if user.activated?
      # Log the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
      log_in user
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
      redirect_to root_url(subdomain: user.subdomain), notice: "Logged in!"
     else
      message  = "Account not activated."
      message += "Check your email for the activation link."
      flash[:warning] = message
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
    render 'new'
  end
end

  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url(subdomain: false)
  end
end
```

Comment: Show the code for your login action on the controller

Comment: Change your conditional statement    if a = b   to   if a == b.

Comment: Are you using ajax to login?

Answer (score 1):

You set up the `current_user` logic wrongly. While comparing any two objects you need to use `==` but you are using `=`. Try changing the `current_user` method to below

```
def current_user
  if (user_id == session[:user_id]) #here
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
  elsif (user_id == cookies.signed[:user_id]) #and here
    user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
    if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
      log_in user
      @current_user = user
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried changing = to == for these two lines and now am getting an error.

Comment: the error is: undefined local variable or method `user_id' Did you mean?  user

Comment: @DamonClark Yeah, that is because you haven't defined `user_id`